# Want to add share via sms option in createChooser method

Tags: java, android, android-intent

By using shareIntent I am only able to choose "email,drive,bluetooth,and shareit". But I also want to add sms option in my shareIntent's createChooser method. I am able to do this using sendIntent object. Can anyone help me to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.vikrant.shareapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button sharebtn,smsbtn;
    String msg = "Welcome to Share app";   // this is the static mssg 
    which our app shows
    Intent shareIntent,sendIntent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sharebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        smsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.smsbtn);
        external_permissions();
    }

    public void external_permissions(){

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
      Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ 
    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
        }
        else{
            sharebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            sharebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("Text/plain");
        shareIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"my app");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,msg);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"shareVia"));

    }

    public void smsSend(View view){
        sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "hello");
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"shareVia"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by daffodil on 11/7/17.
 */
public class ShareIntentActivity  extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button sharebtn,smsbtn;
    String msg = "Welcome to Share app";  
    Intent shareIntent,sendIntent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share_intent);
        sharebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        smsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.smsbtn);
        sharebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        smsbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void external_permissions(){

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
        }
        else{
            sharebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            sharebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        external_permissions();
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("Text/plain");
                shareIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"my app");
                shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,msg);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"shareVia"));
                break;

            case R.id.smsbtn:
                smsSend(v);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void smsSend(View view){
        sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "hello");
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"shareVia"));
    }
}
```

Comment: ur code work same as mine...i want to add sms sharing option in the share Intent's createChooser method...i got the solution by replacing this -->shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  with -->shareIntent = new Intent();......btw thanks for ur reply..

Comment: But i am able to send sms by using this code. What you want exactly please explain.

Comment: i want to show to user all the options for sharing including  share via sms option  when user clicks Button with id button . But in ur code one can only see the share via sms option when user clicks Button with id smsbtn .

Comment: It means you want all the apps installed on your device like watsapp, messanger, skype and message in a single intent ?